# How to put a div above flash file?

Tags: jquery, flash, z-index, conflict

I used [jquery tools tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip.html) and i positioned icons 30 px under flash banner . The problem is when i hover icons , tooltips hide under flash banner , I gave high z-index to the tooltip div or other parent div in order position that above flash banner, but no difference .

Is there any way to overcome this problem ?
At the bottom picture , The green section is flash file and as you can see part of tooltip is hidden 
[alt text http://9139571377325154367-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/dindarbiz/file-cabinet/Image1.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7crSD9impeXl_APuj9p9jAcgiAwkbjAkV2agtMosnVNbW7wwF22_lwu-zgo5TVJ34edVR-5N___RZwIagxb-khFo53wnOkDUJj7pZOOYEeI1it0Cx9e1Dy91dNHlF7RCPvnjtNvJppHBN7NoA80lkz7TtbX3sBsN7m36G6304vSFXsrfJ4Sl_bNajm5F4C5oHa8rM365I7eCzRiJzzvwP421FFjiWg%3D%3D&attredirects=0](http://9139571377325154367-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/dindarbiz/file-cabinet/Image1.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7crSD9impeXl_APuj9p9jAcgiAwkbjAkV2agtMosnVNbW7wwF22_lwu-zgo5TVJ34edVR-5N___RZwIagxb-khFo53wnOkDUJj7pZOOYEeI1it0Cx9e1Dy91dNHlF7RCPvnjtNvJppHBN7NoA80lkz7TtbX3sBsN7m36G6304vSFXsrfJ4Sl_bNajm5F4C5oHa8rM365I7eCzRiJzzvwP421FFjiWg%3D%3D&attredirects=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the wMode to Transparent?  [See here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html)

Answer (score 2):

Flash controls (and other plugin-based controls) in the browser exist in a plane beyond the one that z-index can affect; their rendering doesn't stack with other z-indexed elements in the page.

You can trick the browser into displaying the div above the Flash control by putting an iframe element behind the div. The browser will respect z-index for the iframe, but because the iframe is a totally separate window element, it'll appear above the Flash control.

So you'll now have a Flash element with z-index "x", a div with z-index "y", and an iframe with z-index "z", such that x < z < y.